# Middlewares in golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to chain handlers in my project.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func loggingHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

func loginHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    if req.Method != "POST" {
        http.ServeFile(res, req, "login.html")
        return
    }
    // some code
}

func MainPageHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // some code
}

func main() {
    db, err = sql.Open("", "password@()/db name")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    commonHandlers := alice.New(loggingHandler)
    http.Handle("/Login", commonHandlers.ThenFunc(loginHandler))
    http.Handle("/", commonHandlers.ThenFunc(MainPageHandler))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

what should i do to get an output?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been done many times in Go already.  If you want something light and that comes with some "batteries" included take a look at https://github.com/urfave/negroni  it's very popular and easy to use.  Logging and recovery from panics are standard.

Comment: Recovery from panics is already standard in `net/http`.

Comment: @Tery try to post code that will at least compile (unless you're posting about a compilation issue). The quoted code references `alice` which is not defined or imported.

Answer (score 0):

The request handler can write a response using any of the [`fmt` `Fprint*` methods](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprint) by passing the `http.ResponseWriter` as the first argument.

For example:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "URL.Path = %q\n", r.URL.Path)
}
```